# PHP foreach formatting in columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that works and successfully displays some results based on an SQL query. These results are displayed in **row** format, however I would like to display them in **columns**.

Currently the results are displayed as follows

```
Item Details
Item Details
Item Details
```

However I would like each result in it's own colums like so;

```
Item Details        Item Details        Item Details
```

What should I change in order to do this? Do I need another foreach loop, or do I need to echo the `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">` and `</div>`

My current code is as follows.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <?php 
        foreach ($this->popularBook as $popularBook) {
            echo 'Item Details';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <p>Item Details</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <p>Item Details</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Quite new to SQL and php so any advice/direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class='row'>
<?php foreach ($this->popularBook as $idx => $popularBook) : ?>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'><?php echo $popularBook-title; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```